# Peculiar lack of RHEL 5.8 service management documentation

Tags: rhel, services

I am needing to see the status of some services on some of our RHEL 5.8 hosts on which I am not an admin.  Much to my surprise, I am not able to get any info how to do it (such as `chkconfig` or `systemctl` on Fedora) from Google.  Neither `chkconfig` nor `systemctl` are accessible to me, not sure if it is because of permissions or they are just not available on the system but there are no man pages for either.

Why is it that there is such a mysterious lack of service management documentation online for RHEL 5.8 and which commands can I use for simple service listings?

Comment: Perhaps /usr/sbin is not available in your PATH. Now, you can check if it's there with 'which chkconfig'. And finally, are the manpages installed?

Comment: RHEL 5.8 is similar to Fedora 16 (probably way older, but that one hasn't fallen out of sight yet), the documentation for that one should be applicable. In any case, trawling around the configuration/status of services should be strictly off-limits to the unwashed masses anyway.

Comment: There is no `chkconfig` in my `/usr/sbin`

Answer (score 2):

Your accusation of a lack of documentation for RHEL is extremely poorly founded; RHEL is one of the [best and most comprehensively documented](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/) Linux distributions out there.

[Information on chkconfig](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-services-chkconfig.html), for instance, is in [chapter 18](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-services.html) of the [Deployment Guide](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/index.html).

If you find that your installed system doesn't seem to have utilities or man pages that you expect to be there, contact your system administrator.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=rhel+5.8+service+management&oq=rhel+5.8+service+management&gs_l=serp.3...6572.7868.3.8137.12.12.0.0.0.1.587.1875.5j6j5-1.12.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.uIqBSEI9sLE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=2eac19c5a3f5a464&biw=1396&bih=703

Comment: as opposed to https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=fedora+16+service+management&oq=fedora+16+service+management&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.177373.179552.4.179973.9.9.0.0.0.0.135.799.7j2.9.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.3.psy-ab.WrHiSphYBX0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=2eac19c5a3f5a464&biw=1396&bih=703 which returns the fedora doc on top

Comment: So you're complaining and downvoting me because Google's search results suck?

Comment: any entity can put effort towards their Google presence and control how their data is accessed via Google, especially a sophisticated software house such as Red Hat.  if their documentation regarding a crucial system feature doesn't pop right up when it is simply and clearly sought after in Google, while every other distro's does, it is hard to not blame RH.  unless, of course, GOOG has some sort of a beef with Red Hat but I doubt that

Comment: [Google are Ubuntu fans...](http://www.zdnet.com/the-truth-about-goobuntu-googles-in-house-desktop-ubuntu-linux-7000003462/) That notwithstanding, the fact is that the RHEL documentation is all right there, and very well written, and covers pretty much everything.

Comment: *if their documentation regarding a crucial system feature doesn't pop right up when it is simply and clearly sought after in Google, while every other distro's does, it is hard to not blame RH* -- while it's certainly preferable to have that happen, stop confusing the google search button with actual documentation of anything.

Comment: @RobM -- i see your point, however, in this day and age one simply must take Google as the defacto inescapable interface to all public data.  if your data is not reachable easily through Google, you need to make it happen if you want to publish it and make it accessible.

Comment: If I want to go to the "RHEL Documentation", I'm going to go to the "RHEL Documentation". OK, I lie, I'll Google it. HOLY SHIT FIRST HIT IS https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/. Oh look! There's ALL THE RedHat DOCUMENTATION.

Comment: *one simply must take Google as the defacto inescapable interface to all public data* Well no. One must not. As I said, I'll agree that it's conveniant when that works out, conveniant enough that I'd agree that they should make an effort to ensure it does work, but absence of Google results is not evidence of absence of documentation. If I need to look up some documentation I *start* at the vendor's own website. It's not exactly a hardship.